# Identifying and Resolving Memory Issues with Dompdf in Symfony Application

Tags: php, dompdf

### Problem Description

I'm encountering an out-of-memory issue in my Symfony application while generating PDF files using Dompdf. I suspect there might be a memory leak in the Dompdf library. To investigate, I wrote a script to create multiple PDF files and monitor memory usage.

```php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

ini_set('memory_limit', '20M');

print memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++) {
    print memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;
    createPDF();
}

print memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;

function createPDF () {
    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
}
```

However, running this script results in the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 20971520 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in path/to/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Stylesheet.php on line 281
```

### Question

I suspect there might be a memory leak in the Dompdf library. How can I verify whether the issue is indeed related to Dompdf or if there's another underlying problem causing the memory exhaustion?

### Additional Information

- Symfony version: 4.4.36
- Dompdf version: 2.0.3
- PHP version: 7.4.33

Comment: isn't `20MB` is to small amount of memory to run a Symfony app.

Comment: How many, of the 1000 PDF's you're trying to create, were created before you got the error message?

Comment: You can run `valgrind` to figure out if it's indeed the case. A bug report can be filed with https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues if it's reproducible on the trunk version. The library is known to have had memory leaks in the past, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is the case here, too.

Comment: I tried `valgrind`, couldn't find anything specific to the script, `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all php -f index.php`

Comment: It's not in dompdf itself, it's likely in the ext-dom extension, which uses libxml, among some other things. I ran a couple of grinds and saw this, checking in PHP 8.3 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the PHP garbage collector is not kicking in.

If you add `gc_collect_cycles()` inside `createPDF()` you can force garbage collection.

You can trace the GC via:

```
php -dmemory_limit=7M -dxdebug.mode=gcstats -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes min.php
```

And look for `gcstats` files in /tmp/ or wherever you set XDebug output to.

So why is the garbage collector not kicking in? Well, as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php:

> When the garbage collector is turned on, the cycle-finding algorithm as described above is executed whenever the root buffer runs full. The root buffer has a fixed size of 10,000 possible roots (although you can alter this by changing the GC_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT constant in Zend/zend_gc.c in the PHP source code, and re-compiling PHP). When the garbage collector is turned off, the cycle-finding algorithm will never run. However, possible roots will always be recorded in the root buffer, no matter whether the garbage collection mechanism has been activated with this configuration setting.

As the a `DomPdf` instance takes up quite a hefty chunk of memory with each iteration (a lot of it is in `FontMetrics` caching), not enough objects (it's a small library) are in the root buffer to spawn the GC before running out of memory.

If you run `gc_status()` at the end of `createPdf` you'll see that after one run you get a mere ~150 roots (depending on the chosen adapter). For 20M you'll get about 7000 roots, short of the 10k threshold. And if you increase the limit to 40M the script finishes successfully with 8 GC runs never running out of memory:

```
Garbage Collection Report
version: 1
creator: xdebug 3.2.0 (PHP 8.2.1)

Collected | Efficiency% | Duration | Memory Before | Memory After | Reduction% | Function
----------+-------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------
    87815 |    878.15 % | 12.88 ms |      28461832 |      5090000 |    82.12 % | Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet::apply_styles
    88140 |    881.40 % | 14.66 ms |      28556032 |      5090000 |    82.18 % | Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet::apply_styles
    88140 |    881.40 % | 15.01 ms |      28556032 |      5090000 |    82.18 % | Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet::apply_styles
    88140 |    881.40 % | 15.43 ms |      28556032 |      5090000 |    82.18 % | Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet::apply_styles
```

Comment: A very nice answer. I was trying to get Unnikrishnan there, but he never bothered to answer a simple question. I hope he appreciates it.

Comment: Wonderful! After adding the function `gc_collect_cycles()`, it started working fine. Thanks for the help!